# Compile Error: Declaration of Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Translation\Loader\DatabaseLoader::load

Tags: php, symfony

First time using the TranslationBundle and im unsure why this error occurs.
I tried Updating the Package to the latest version and all of its dependencies but it does not solve it.

Here is the full error:

> HTTP 500 Internal Server Error Compile Error: Declaration of
> Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Translation\Loader\DatabaseLoader::load($resource,
> $locale, $domain = 'messages') must be compatible with
> Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\LoaderInterface::load(mixed
> $resource, string $locale, string $domain = 'messages'):
> Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue

Here is my composer file

```
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true,
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.12",
    "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "*",
    "jms/serializer": "^3.12",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^3.9",
    "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.11",
    "lexik/translation-bundle": "*",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^4.2",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.1",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.4",
    "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.4",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.4",
    "symfony/asset": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/console": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/form": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/property-access": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/property-info": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/serializer": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.5",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/validator": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "5.4.*",
    "symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle": "^1.7",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.17"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/css-selector": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/debug-bundle": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.2",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "5.4.*"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true,
    "secure-http": false,
    "allow-plugins": {
        "symfony/flex": true
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "5.4.*"
    }
}
```

}

Would love to understand the full picture on why this is happening.

EDIT: Here are the versions:

```
        "name": "lexik/translation-bundle",
        "version": "v5.2.0",

        "name": "symfony/translation",
        "version": "v6.0.7",
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Looks like you are using a version of `lexik/translation-bundle`  that is not compatible with the version of `symfony/translation`

Comment: How do you know that it's not compatible ?

Comment: Isn't that what the error message tells you? Please add the exact versions you are using of these two packages to your question by editing it

Comment: Hello, i added the versions @NicoHaase

Comment: Please, do not [repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71990092/compile-error-declaration-of-class-must-be-compatible-with).

Answer (score 1):

`lexik/translation-bundle` is not compatible with Symfony 6. There's already a [bug report](https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle/issues/406) about this, but without any merged pull requests.

Either wait for that package to be made compatible, or downgrade your Symfony version to 5.4